# How to open multiple windows using WPF Prism library?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm new to the `PRISM` library. Although it updated quickly, the documentation is confusing, incomplete, and mixes many versions. Currently, I'm using `PRISM 8`.

I would like some help with an example of how to open multiple windows (modal and non-modal) from main window buttons, sending parameters, and receiving messages, because I was only able to found examples of UserControl View injected into a Window View.

Answer (score 1):

The Prism library does not limit you in any way to use windows like you would in WPF without it. You can write your own window service that suits your requirements to manage instantiating and showing windows. How you implement communication between them is up to you. You could communicate between view models using Prism's event aggregator.

The `IDialogService` is a feature introduced in Prism 7.2.0.1367, which is a built-it implementation of such a service. The [documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html) for it is up-to-date and there is not much to add, as it covers everything from creating dialogs, passing parameters, showing dialogs, as well as registering custom windows and styling.

The only thing that changes in Prism 8 is that you can now register multiple dialog windows .

```
// Default dialog window
containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<MyDialogWindow>();

// Another dialog window that can be accessed by name
containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<MyOtherDialogWindow>(nameof(MyOtherDialogWindow));
```

You can refer to them by name when showing a dialog with the dialog service.

```
// Shows the dialog view in them default dialog window
dialogService.Show(nameof(MyView), new DialogParameters(), result => { /* ...handle result.*/ });

// Shows the dialog view in the "MyOtherDialogWindow"
dialogService.Show(nameof(MyView), new DialogParameters(), result => { /* ...handle result.*/ }, nameof(MyOtherDialogWindow));
```

> I would like some help with an example of how to open multiple windows (modal and non-modal) from a main window buttons, [...]

You need to access the `IDialogService` in your view model. Pass it in the constructor and store it in a field. The dependency container will inject it automatically.

```
private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

public MyViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
{
   _dialogService = dialogService;
}
```

Create a `ICommand` property in your view model that a button in your view binds to.

```
OpenDialogCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExceuteOpenDialog);
```

In the execute method, create the dialog paramaters and show the dialog with `Show` or `ShowDialog` (modal).

```
private void ExceuteOpenDialog()
{
   dialogService.Show(nameof(MyOtherView), new DialogParameters(), result => { /* ...handle result.*/ });
}
```

> [...] sending parameters and receiving messages, [...]

That depends on your requirements, but you can have a look at the event aggregator. The [documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/event-aggregator.html) is still valid and comprehensive, so nothing to add.

> [...] I was only able to found examples of UserControl View injected into a Window View.

That is how the dialog service works. You can use any `UserControl` to be displayed in a dialog. The dialog service automatically places it in a dialog host window. This way you can **reuse** your view and make it easier to change and maintain. If you would define your view as `Window`, you would lose the flexibility of applying different dialog windows without changing the view type and its XAML, as well as the ability to use it anywhere else within other views as component.